# Create a Cert from .cer and .p7b in SQL Server 2017 Linux image running in a Docker Container

Tags: docker, encryption, sql-server-2017

I have downloaded the SQL Server 2017 Linux image and ran in a Container.
Next I have connected to the container from SQL Server Management Studio 2017.
I then used "docker cp" to copy a .bak file to "/var/opt/mssql/backup".

But it needs an encryption key to restore.

So in SSMS I open a query window for the container and run these commands:

```
USE master;
GO

CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'P@ssw0rd';
GO

CREATE CERTIFICATE CertificateName FROM FILE = 'C:\cert.cer' WITH PRIVATE 
KEY (FILE = 'C:\key.p7b', DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '********');
```

When I run the last one I get this error:
"The certificate, asymmetric key, or private key file is not valid or does not exist; or you do not have permissions for it."

How do I do this for a Docker Container?
Can I get the files from the local file system?
Or do I need to copy it into "/var/opt/mssql/" and somehow get from there?

Answer (score 1):

Docker apparently couldn't read the cer and key files form the local file system.
Here is what I did:

At command prompt make a dir in the container to hold the keys.

```
docker exec -it sqlcontainer1 mkdir /var/opt/mssql/setup
docker cp "C:\Temp\cert.cer" sqlcontainer1:/var/opt/mssql/setup
docker cp "C:\Temp\key.p7b" sqlcontainer1:/var/opt/mssql/setup
```

Then I went back into SSMS and ran the commands again:

```
--DROP MASTER KEY

CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '********';
GO

CREATE CERTIFICATE CertName FROM FILE = '/var/opt/mssql/setup/cert.cer' WITH 
PRIVATE KEY (FILE = '/var/opt/mssql/setup/key.p7b', DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 
'********');
```